# How to replace a hyphen with a word

Tags: text-processing

I have the following  text:

```
Since the 1-93 fragment contains additional
residues 84–93.
```

The first hypen found in "1-93" is fine when I process the text  but the second one, am not sure it is a hypen or another character that caused my problems, so I need to replace this "–" in text so at the end to get:

84 to 93 instead. Kindly how to do that.

Comment: `printf %s – | recode ..dump` tells you what character it is ([U+2013, en dash](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm) here)

Answer (score 2):

You can always use a tool such as octal dump (`od`) or `hexdump` to confirm the ASCII code for a given character.

#### Example

```
$ echo 'Since the 1-93 fragment contains additional
residues 84–93.' | hexdump -C
00000000  53 69 6e 63 65 20 74 68  65 20 31 2d 39 33 20 66  |Since the 1-93 f|
00000010  72 61 67 6d 65 6e 74 20  63 6f 6e 74 61 69 6e 73  |ragment contains|
00000020  20 61 64 64 69 74 69 6f  6e 61 6c 0a 72 65 73 69  | additional.resi|
00000030  64 75 65 73 20 38 34 e2  80 93 39 33 2e 0a        |dues 84...93..|
0000003e
```

So the first `-` is ASCII code `2d`, while the second `–` is not an ASCII code at all. So the dashes are clearly different. It's actually a UTF-8 character `0xe28093`, an EN-DASH. (Thanks to [@casey](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/53706/casey) for clarifying this!)

To replace a character in a string such as this you can use either `sed` or put the string in a variable and do a search and replace on the string for this one character.

*sed*

```
$ var='Since the 1-93 fragment contains additional\nresidues 84–93.'
$ echo -e $var | sed 's/–/-/g'
Since the 1-93 fragment contains additional
residues 84-93.
```

*bash*

```
$ var='Since the 1-93 fragment contains additional\nresidues 84–93.'
$ echo -e ${var/–/-}
Since the 1-93 fragment contains additional
residues 84-93.
```

Comment: Note that the second dash is not ASCII e2, it is UTF-8 0xe28093, which is the EN-DASH character.

Comment: @casey - thanks that make a lot more sense, I wasn't sure what `od` was saying to me last night 8-). I've included your note in the A.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed`:

```
$ echo "Since the 1-93 fragment contains additional
> residues 84–93." | sed 's/–/ to /g'

Since the 1-93 fragment contains additional
residues 84 to 93.
```

To edit multiple files in-place, we use GNU `sed`, you can do:

```
sed -i 's/–/ to /g' ./*.txt
```

Comment: I need all of cases in text files not just in one sentence. I have many text files (*.txt)

Comment: Updated answer!